# How to “tripartite” a tree using 0, 1 and 2 and maximize the numbers used?

Tags: graph, tree, dynamic-programming

An interesting problem is to assign labels (0, 1 or 2) for every node in a tree (not necessarily binary), where no parent-child pair can have the same label. In addition, we need to maximize the sum of all labels, i.e., use as little 0 as possible. Return the minimum number of 0 labels used. Some leaf nodes have been pre-labeled. We cannot change those labels. If there are no way to assign labels, for example, one parent node has children pre-labeled with all three labels, return negative infinity.

I am trying dynamic programming on this. One possible recurrence is that OPT(v) returns the number of 0 used to label v’s subtree, and we start at the overall root. When recurse down the tree, try to label each v’s children 0, 1 and 2 (by manipulating v.label field in each node) and see which option returns the minimum number of 0. If we reach bottom and a leaf node has been pre-labeled, we can’t explore all labels but to use the given label. If the leaf node is not pre-labeled, try each label, same as above. The tree itself can be used as my memorization structure where the label is stored in each node’s .label field. But I am not sure how to write the recurrence explicitly, especially for the recursive case when I explore all possible labels for every child of current node. I have no idea to express this combination and get the minimum of it. The base case is fairly simple, perhaps return 1 if the leaf is labeled 0 and return 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea looks fine. Just one thing to improve: the memoization should concern not just one label value, but possibly all 3 label values (0, 1 and 2). For each label you would (per node) memoize what the minimum number of zeroes is in that node's tree (where it is the root) when that label is assigned to it.

Then, depending on which choice you made for the parent node, you would look at the two possible labels that remain and choose the label which has the least number of zeroes linked to it.

For the below implementation I have used this tree as example:

```
          *
        /    \
       *      * ___
      /|\    / \   \
     1 * *  2   *   *
               / \   \
              *   2   2
             /|\
            2 * 0
```

The asterisks are nodes that have no label.

So the algorithm would start at the root and temporarily assign it a 0, then see what effect and possibilities that leaves for the children. Then for each child go through the possible values it can have (not zero), ...and recurse deeper into the tree, each time backtracking -- registering the count of 0 labels -- and continuing with the next possible label for the node (and going down the tree again unless memoization is available).

For the above example we can see that an optimal labeling would be:

```
          0
        /    \
       2      1 ___
      /|\    / \   \
     1 1 1  2   0   0
               / \   \
              1   2   2
             /|\
            2 2 0
```

The root and its left child could swap values -- it doesn't matter. The result is 4 zeroes.

Here is the implementation:

```js
// Main algorithm:
function triple(node, parentLabel=-1) {
    let choices = node.label !== undefined ? [node.label] : [0,1,2];
    let minCount = Infinity;
    for (let label of choices) {
        if (label === parentLabel) continue; // We cannot use same label as parent has
        let count = node.memo[label]; // Already memoized?
        if (count === undefined) { // No...
            count = 0;
            for (let child of node.children) {
                count += triple(child, label); // recur
                if (count >= minCount) break; // not better...
            }
            node.memo[label] = count;
        }
        if (label === 0) count++; // Count the zero
        if (count < minCount) minCount = count; // better!
    }
    // Minimum number of 0-labels if parent has the given parentLabel
    return minCount;
}

class Node {
    constructor(label, ...children) {
        this.label = label;
        this.children = children;
        this.memo = [undefined, undefined, undefined];
    }
}

// Short-cut function for creating a Node instance with or without label
function N(...children) {
    let label = undefined;
    if (typeof children[0] === "number") { // first argument is a label
        label = children.shift(); // extract first argument
    }
    return new Node(label, ...children);
}

// Demo
let tree = N(
    N(
        N(1), N(), N()
    ),
    N(
        N(2),
        N(
            N(
                N(2), N(), N(0)
            ),
            N(2)
        ),
        N(
            N(2)
        )
    )
)

console.log("input tree:");
console.log(tree);
let count = triple(tree);
console.log("Number of zeroes:", count);
```

This implementation would return Infinity when there is no valid labelling possible.